# C# - Reading from JSON file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I have problem with reading JSON file. File is inserted into Solution Explorer with Build Action set to Content and copy property se to Copy Always. I would expect then the file should be reachable from app in LocalFolder.

```
Stream localFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("sources.json");

string json;

using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(localFolder))
{
    json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SourceDefinition>>(json);
```

The error it is returning is:

> Error: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Error: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Comment: Are you getting the error when running through the Visual Studio or after the app is deployed?  Also where exactly in you app did you place the file?

Comment: During debugging in Visual Studio. The code is placed in Background task (separated project but placed in same solution as main part of my app). I tried to place my sources.json file in both project's root but without any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try File.OpenRead - you're propably trying to open from AppData which is a special path within thr userprofile (%localappdata% in this case)

Answer (score 1):

So the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder point to the users\XXXXX\Local\Packages\YYYYYY\LocalState where XXXX is the user and YYYY is the GUID for your app.  No folder in the project explorer actually points to that location to the best of my knowledge.   You can try using the Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.  The InstalledLocation.Path will get you access to the bin where the app is running.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this code for reading the json file on a scalable manner and binding to list model class

```
appsettings.json File

    "Mapping": {
        "Column1": {
          "ExcelColumnName": "DISTRIBUTOR UNIQUE ID",
          "DbFieldName": "vehicle_dealer_code",
          "IsRequired": "true",
          "DataType": ""
        },
        "Column1": {
          "ExcelColumnName": "FACTORY ORDER NUMBER",
          "DbFieldName": "vehicle_data02",
          "IsRequired": "true",
          "DataType": ""
        }
    public static T InitOptions<T>(string name, string section) where T : new()
            {
                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                 .AddJsonFile(name, true, true)
                 .Build();
                return config.GetSection(section).Get<T>();
            }

   

    public class Config
        {
            public Mapping Column1 { get; set; }
            public Mapping Column2 { get; set; }        
        }

public class Mapping
{
    public string ExcelColumnName { get; set; }
    public string DbFieldName { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
}

var MappedData = InitOptions<Config>("appsettings.json", "Mapping");
```

Comment: Hey, this question was from a long time ago and already answered. Your answer is very thorough though and appreciated. Please consider helping with some of the more recent posts.